# Form Level Events wont fire

Tags: parsley.js

Ok, i am thinking this is something  stupid, but i cant put my finger on it.

I have a form that I am using parsley with. Parsley is initialize in the document ready handler, and subsequently registers two event handlers, one for when the form fails validation, the other for when it succeeds. It then calls the form validation programmatically. The validation works, the field are shown with errors, but the event handlers dont fire.

Here is a code that exemplifies the behavior:

```
Query(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#user-password-reset-form").parsley();
    jQuery("#user-password-reset-form").parsley().on("form:success", function () {
        console.log("Success");
        jQuery("#user-password-reset-dialog").find(".apply-password-reset").prop("disabled",false);
    });
    jQuery("#user-password-reset-form").parsley().on("form:fail", function () {
        console.log("Fail");
        jQuery("#user-password-reset-dialog").find(".apply-password-reset").prop("disabled",true);
    });

    jQuery("#user-password-reset-form").parsley().validate();   
    console.log("Initialized")
})
```

You can run it here: https://jsfiddle.net/L5or6ofb/

Are the form level event handlers supposed to fire when validation is triggered programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure event is called `'form:error'` (not `'form:fail'`).

Comment: As i said, something stupid. Thanks for the response.